# Dynamic videos on videojs

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, video.js

I need to use videojs to show some videos. An usual video declaration looks like this (for 2 videos on this example):

```
var videos = [
        {
          src : [
            'http://demo.dealerpro.net/Images/Sites/577/videos/HondaHands.mp4'
          ],
          poster : 'http://i145.photobucket.com/albums/r217/Carnifreekshow/Asus%20Orion%20Repair/before_zps12ce48a2.jpg',
          title : 'Honda. The Power of Dreams.'
        },
        {
          src : [
            'http://1eb9cddbb30a65a675d4-91fe7d858d3e9c59dcdfd3e789416fbc.r56.cf1.rackcdn.com/Sites/577/commercial.mp4'
          ],
          poster : 'http://i145.photobucket.com/albums/r217/Carnifreekshow/Asus%20Orion%20Repair/before_zps12ce48a2.jpg',
          title : 'Thanks for Making Us #1'
        }
      ];
```

I have the src, poster and title information of some videos on another array, and I need to declare it dynamically depending on some filters. I need to do something like this:

```
            for (var index = 0;index<totalVideos;index++)
            {
                var videos = [
                {
                    src : [
                        sourceArray[index]
                    ],
                    poster : posterArray[index],
                    title : titleArray[index]
                }

                ];
            }
```

But this is not working, anyone know how can I declare videos dynamically to be used on videojs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve it, below is my solution:

```
    var totalVideos = 3;//put the ammount of videos you want to dynamically add

    /*You need to fill this arrays with the information of your videos*/
    var arrayTitles = new Array(totalVideos);
    var arraySources = new Array(totalVideos);
    var arrayPosters = new Array(totalVideos);

    var videos = new Array(totalVideos);
    for (var index = 0;index<totalVideos;index++)
    {        
      var theVideo = {
        src: [
          arraySources[index]
        ],
        poster: arrayPosters[index],
        title: arrayTitles[index]
      };
      videos[index] = theVideo;
    }
```

After this you can start working with the videos variable with videojs. In my case I'm doing a filter, so when you select an option you just see the videos that were selected on the filter.